# knockout checking if variable returns true and false

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a few instances in my application where I am setting a style if a variable is present and it is working fine.

However, I just ran into a case where I need to manipulate that variable to always be there, but have a value of either true or false. I have tried a few things, but everything I try seems to blow knockout up telling me either that the data-bind item does not exist r it is not a boolean value.

My data-bond looks like this without any modifications and it works fine if the value is not false.

```
<div data-bind="style: {float: Show() ? 'right' : 'none', width: Show() ? '70%' : '100%'}">
```

And I have tried

```
<div data-bind="style: {float: Show() != false  ? 'right' : 'none', width: Show() != false ? '70%' : '100%'}">
```

Both with quotes around the false and without

and I have tried

```
<div data-bind="style: {float: Show() > 0  ? 'right' : 'none', width: Show() > 0  ? '70%' : '100%'}">
```

But this just returns that it is not a boolean

This is what the variable looks like coming back from the view

```
if(this.app.get('Wait').length === 0){
    model.Show = false;
}else{
    model.Show = ko.observable(JSON.parse(this.model.get('Show')));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What about using `Show` instead of `Show()`

Comment: That works if the list was always hidden, but when it needs to display it throws an error

Comment: What is the error that it throws?

Comment: During view initialization viewModel creation failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u When I was researching this before I was told that I needed the () because it was technically a function

Comment: Sounds like `this.model.get('Show')` is returning `undefined` so you may want to change to `JSON.parse(this.model.get('Show') || "false")` or just otherwise check that that property is available.

Comment: No, it never returns undefined. It is only ever returning true or false, I have done extensive breakpoints to make sure. That error is only happening if I add anything after either show() or show in the style (like checking if it's true or false) I have this working with just the show() in multiple other places.

Comment: Sidenote, it'd be better to put that styling in CSS and have a class toggled on and off with an observable.

Comment: @Retsam Normally I would do that, but this is something that I don't want the client to have access to and change (changing this would break the app) and the client has access to the css file. So I'm trying to 'hide' it essentially.

Answer (score 1):

If in the view you are always deal with the function, so make sure the property you deal with is always function whether it `TRUE` or `FALSE`

I've notice you was initialize `Show` property as/with a boolean:

```
if(this.app.get('Wait').length === 0){
    model.Show = false; // HERE IS INCORRECT
}else{
    model.Show = ko.observable(JSON.parse(this.model.get('Show')));
}
```

So try to early define your `Show` property as a observable, then update the observable value by something like this:

```
model.Show = ko.observable(false); // Define with default value wheter TRUE or FALSE

if(this.app.get('Wait').length === 0)
{
    model.Show(false); 
}
else
{
    model.Show(JSON.parse(this.model.get('Show')));
}
```

Then, in the view you can always use it like this:

```
// Check whether value is FALSE
<div data-bind="style: { float: ! Show() ? 'right' : 'none' }">

// Check whether value is TRUE
<div data-bind="style: { float: Show() ? 'right' : 'none' }">
```

Comment: You can simplify into `model.Show = ko.observable(this.app.get('Wait').length ? JSON.parse(this.model.get('Show') : false);`